# saving many intgers into 1 integer

Tags: java, python, unsigned-integer

I am trying to save many natural numbers that are smaller than m into 1 natural number n.
I need a function to read i'th number from n.
In python I can do it like:

```
def read(n,m,i):#reads a number on index i from n.
    return n//m**i%m
def save(numbers_to_save, m=None):#saves natural numbers, that are smaller than m to n.
    if m is None:
        m=max(numbers_to_save)+1
    n=0
    for i_number in range(len(numbers_to_save)):
        n+=m**i_number*numbers_to_save[i_number]
    return n

numbers_to_save=[12,54,3,7,23,8,9,3,72,3]
i_max=len(numbers_to_save)
m=max(numbers_to_save)+1
n=save(numbers_to_save,m)
del numbers_to_save

for i in range(i_max):
    print(read(n,m,i),end=",")
```

But how to do it effectively in java reading n only byte per byte? n is bigger than maximum value of long, so I can not use long to save n.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the title? And what language exactly do you want to convert the code to? Most languages have utilities for infinite precision integers, and you can always implement Python's trick yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I changed title now.

Comment: Why would any1 ever want to do that?

Comment: @JayC667, I want to demonstrait a unespected output of a java program, that I think is caused by bug in java. I need to load data for that. Since i can not add separate file for data, I decided to put data into sourcecode as string. Since data is big, I wanted to compress it. This is a method to compress the data.

Comment: @JayC667, it is data compression algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To translate this code to Java, you would need to use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

It works similarly to Python's "infinite" size integers, but with two key differences:

1. It is immutable, which means every time you change it, the result is a new object you must store in place of the old one.
2. You can't use regular operators (+, -, *, +) on it directly, but instead you must use the instance methods such as `add` or `pow`.

Here is an example of how your `read` function will look in Java:

```
int read(BigInteger n, BigInteger m, int i) {
    return n.divide(m.pow(i)).mod(m).intValue();
}
```

Note, that for simplicity, this code assumes that both `i` and `m` will be smaller than `MAX_INT`.

It is possible to make both of them `BigInteger` as well to allow them to be of any size.

Comment: Thanx, but could this be done better by reading n byte per byte or long by long?

Comment: @user2952903 what do you mean? If you can use an array of `long` you don't need the whole algorithm with the calculations, you just use array as usual. What are you trying to do?

Comment: To save 10000 natural numbers, that are smaller than 129, using 1 byte for every number I need 10000 bytes, but to save 10000 numbers, that are smaller than 129, using my algorithm I need 1 number (n), that is smaller than 129\**10000 and takes only 8765 bytes.

To save 10000 natural numbers, that are smaller than 3, using 1 byte for every number I need 10000 bytes, but to save 10000 numbers, that are smaller than 3, using my algorithm I need 1 number (n), that is smaller than 3\**10000 and takes only 1982 bytes.

Comment: So it is data compression algorithm.

Comment: @user2952903 well, `BigInt` already does pretty much that, by using array of integers just big enough to store the final number. https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java But, if you don't like that implementation, and want to work with a clean array, you can. "Better" though, will depend on you usage of this array. For example, if access speed is critical, it is better to waste a couple of thousand bytes of RAM on an uncompressed array.

Comment: @user2952903 one problem to note with Java is that is does not have unsigned integer types, which makes bit shifts tricky.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` can be used for that specific given numbers (since `m**count < Long.MAX_VALUE`).

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

    public static long save(int m, int... numbers) {
        long result = 0;
        long mult = 1;
        for (var num : numbers) {
            if (num <0 || num >= m) throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid: " + num);
            result = addExact(result, multiplyExact(mult, num));
            mult = multiplyExact(mult, m);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static int read(long compressed, int m, int i) {
        return (int) (compressed / (long)pow(m, i) % m);
    }
    
    private static void test() {
        int[] numbers = { 12, 54, 3, 7, 23, 8, 9, 3, 72, 3};
        int m = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().orElseThrow() + 1;
        long compressed = save(m, numbers);
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int val = read(compressed, m, i);
            if (val == numbers[i])
                System.out.println(val);
            else
                System.err.printf("%d != %d @ %d%n", val, numbers[i], i);
        }
    }
```

I am a bit lazy, so I used the `Math` methods `addExactly` and `multiplyExact` that throw an Exception in case of overflow. Alternative: check if `long` can save that count of numbers given `m` at start of method and use

```
    result += mult * num;
    mult *= m;
```

instead in the loop.

Use `BigInteger` as posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67557380/15793316)),  if *more space* is needed.

<sup>this code also works with `int` to compress less, smaller values</sup>